# How to copy multiple files and use a wildcard

Tags: delphi

Any ideas why this doesn't work? No errors, my text files just don't copy.

```
procedure TForm1.CopyFiles(Source, Target: string);
var
FO: TShFileOpStruct;
begin
   FillChar(FO,SizeOf(FO),#0);
   FO.Wnd := Form1.Handle;
   FO.wFunc := FO_COPY;
   FO.pFrom := PChar(Source);
   FO.pTo := PChar(Target);
   ShFileOperation(FO);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    CopyFiles('c:\test\*.txt','c:\test2\');
end;
```

Comment: Have you checked the result from `SHFileOperation`?

Comment: Not sure how to, do you mind explaining?

Comment: Don't use the global variable `Form1` in a `TForm1` method. Use `Self`, or omit it and thereby use it implicitly. A very wise move is to delete the global form variables.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why that's a good idea?

Comment: What happens when you have two instances of a form? At that point, your code that uses the global variable will always refer to the same instance. These global variables were only ever added to make it easy for VB developers to migrate to Delphi back in the early 1990s. Global variables are generally considered a bad thing: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no errors because you don't check the return value of the call to `SHFileOperation`. There could be an error, but you cannot know about it because you neglect to check for it.

The other problem you have is that you failed to double null terminate the strings, as stated in the documentation. So that like so:

```
FO.pFrom := PChar(Source + #0);
FO.pTo := PChar(Target + #0);
```

Given these mistakes that you have made, I suggest that you have another close read of the documentation.